# java:How to convert multi linestring to polygon

Tags: java, geotools

I got two contour linestrings of some canyon area but they didn't close. Clearly they does represent a area of result.How do I close them by code?

Let's say the two linestring like

```
    LineString lineString1 = geometryFactory.createLineString(new Coordinate[]{
            new Coordinate(0, 0),
            new Coordinate(10, 0)
    });

    LineString lineString2 = geometryFactory.createLineString(new Coordinate[]{
            new Coordinate(0, 2),
            new Coordinate(10, 2)
    });

    List<LineString> lineStrings = Arrays.asList(lineString1, lineString2);
    Geometry geometry = geometryFactory.buildGeometry(lineStrings);
    // MULTILINESTRING ((0 0, 10 0), (0 2, 10 2))

    Geometry union = geometry.union();
    // MULTILINESTRING ((0 0, 10 0), (0 2, 10 2))

    LinearRing linearRing = geometryFactory.createLinearRing(geometry.getCoordinates());
    // Exception: Points of LinearRing do not form a closed linestring
```

How can I get the result

```
LINESTRING ((0 0, 10 0, 10 2, 0 2, 0 0))
```

Any help is appreciate.

Comment: The concept you are looking for is convex hull or convex envelope.

Comment: @PaulJanssens Code above was just to simplify the question, actual result was more like 'Y' shape or 'X' shape or even more complicate.The convex hull will just get the outer ring.

Comment: Make a list of all discontinuities and pair them up with the nearest neighbour?